# Index Match to match date between two dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a date column B that are dates. My Fiscal year begins April 1 and ends March 31, I have my date ranges below:

[image]

[image]

Here is my formula including named ranges. I'm getting N/A error, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

`{=INDEX(fiscalyear,MATCH(1,(startdate>=B2)*(enddate<=B2),0))}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of the lookup with:

```
="FY" & YEAR(EOMONTH(B2,9))
```

Comment: Clever, thanks, I honestly wouldn't have thought about looking at it this way.

Answer (score 2):

Since any fiscal year starts right after a fiscal year ends you can just use:

```
=INDEX(fiscalyear,MATCH(B2,startdate,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Although both of the previous answers are correct and the formulas are simpler than the original one, I would like to point out where the original problem was - the comparison operators were swapped there.

It was:

```
{=INDEX(fiscalyear,MATCH(1,(startdate>=B2)*(enddate<=B2),0))}
```

Must be:

```
{=INDEX(fiscalyear,MATCH(1,(startdate<=B2)*(enddate>=B2),0))}
```

Comment: Thank you, the other tips are useful for this exact purpose, but this formula is more adaptable for other use cases... And it was driving me crazy.